# Domino server sending return receipts eventhough it's disabled

Tags: lotus-notes

I'm unsure whether this should be posted here or on StackOverflow, so I apologize in advance if this is the wrong site.

I'm fairly new to Domino administration. I have a problem regarding return receipts on our Domino 9 server. I've been asked to disable all return receipts from our server. I've found the place where it's disabled:

[image]

After this I have retarted the server, but we still send out return receipts when getting mails. I have tested from an Outlook 2013 client. Is this how it is or am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That option does not disable sending return receipts back to non-Domino senders.

That option disables some Domino users's ability to request return receipts from non-Domino users.  (But it's really not that effective, because it only works for users who are set up to generate their messages using Notes/Domino's internal rich text format.  Users who are set up to generate their messages in MIME format don't require this conversion, so their return receipt requests will go through.)

Comment: Do you know what option does globally disable return receipts? Or is it not possible?

Comment: I've tested the following:

http://steviouscam.homelinux.com/BlockingReturnReceipts.html

It only seem to work on Domino to Domino mails for me though.

Comment: I am not aware of a way to have the server block return receipts.  At least, not a simple way that would work only for blocking external return receipts.

Answer (score 0):

Blocking return receipts in Notes/Domino can be done on the client side by hex-editing the nnotesws.dll file and changing the ReturnReceipt string to something else.
That's the only real and effective way to disable it.

There are cleaner but much more involved or cumbersome ways to do it:

- alter the mail template to either strip out or change the value of the ReturnReceipt field on a QueryOpenDocument event
- only ever read mail using preview, and have preview set up not to send return receipts (which is the default setting, controlled by File > Preferences > Basic Notes Client Configuration > Additional options > Mark documents read when opened in the preview pane)